# Problems setting self-signed ssl certificate in couchdb at ubuntu ec2

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I'm trying to replicate the same environment in my pc (ubuntu 12.10) to aws ec2 (ubuntu 12.04).

So I executed the following commands:

```
# openssl genrsa -out localhost.key 2048

# openssl req -new -x509 -key localhost.key -out localhost.crt -days 3650 -subj /CN=localhost
```

After that, I configure the the local.ini as follow: (making sure that those certificate files are acessible from couchdb user):

```
[daemons]
httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}

[ssl]
cert_file = /opt/couchdb/etc/cert/localhost.crt
key_file = /opt/couchdb/etc/cert/localhost.key
```

When I run this command at my pc, this works fine,

```
curl -v -k https://localhost:6984/
```

but at aws ec2 I get the follow error:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 6984 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:6984 
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:6984
```

the couch log:

```
Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:27:57 GMT] [error] [<0.3024.1>] {error_report,<0.61.0>,
                                   {<0.3024.1>,std_error,
                                    [83,83,76,58,32,"1095",58,32,"error",58,
                                     [123,
                                      ["try_clause",44,
                                       [123,["error",44,"eacces"],125]],
                                      125],
                                     32,
                                     "/usr/local/etc/couchdb/cert/localhost.crt",
                                     "\n",32,32,
                                     [91,
                                      [[123,
                                        ["ssl_manager",44,"cache_pem_file",44,
                                         "2"],
                                        125],
                                       44,10,"   ",
                                       [123,
                                        ["ssl_certificate",44,
                                         "file_to_certificats",44,"2"],
                                        125],
                                       44,10,"   ",
                                       [123,
                                        ["ssl_connection",44,
                                         "init_certificates",44,"6"],
                                        125],
                                       44,10,"   ",
                                       [123,
                                        ["ssl_connection",44,"ssl_init",44,
                                         "2"],
                                        125],
                                       44,10,"   ",
                                       [123,
                                        ["ssl_connection",44,"init",44,"1"],
                                        125],
                                       44,10,"   ",
                                       [123,
                                        ["gen_fsm",44,"init_it",44,"6"],
                                        125],
                                       44,10,"   ",
                                       [123,
                                        ["proc_lib",44,"init_p_do_apply",44,
                                         "3"],
                                        125]],
                                      93],
                                     "\n"]}}
[Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:27:57 GMT] [error] [<0.3024.1>] {error_report,<0.61.0>,
                         {<0.3024.1>,crash_report,
                          [[{initial_call,
                                {ssl_connection,init,['Argument__1']}},
                            {pid,<0.3024.1>},
                            {registered_name,[]},
                            {error_info,
                                {exit,ecertfile,
                                    [{gen_fsm,init_it,6},
                                     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                            {ancestors,[ssl_connection_sup,ssl_sup,<0.62.0>]},
                            {messages,[]},
                            {links,[<0.66.0>]},
                            {dictionary,[]},
                            {trap_exit,false},
                            {status,running},
                            {heap_size,2584},
                            {stack_size,24},
                            {reductions,1532}],
                           []]}}
[Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:27:57 GMT] [error] [<0.66.0>] {error_report,<0.61.0>,
                       {<0.66.0>,supervisor_report,
                        [{supervisor,{local,ssl_connection_sup}},
                         {errorContext,child_terminated},
                         {reason,ecertfile},
                         {offender,
                             [{pid,<0.3024.1>},
                              {name,undefined},
                              {mfargs,{ssl_connection,start_link,undefined}},
                              {restart_type,temporary},
                              {shutdown,4000},
                              {child_type,worker}]}]}}
[Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:27:57 GMT] [error] [<0.349.1>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                                  {<0.349.1>,std_error,
                                   [{application,mochiweb},
                                    "Accept failed error",
                                    "{error,ecertfile}"]}}
[Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:27:57 GMT] [error] [<0.349.1>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                        {<0.349.1>,crash_report,
                         [[{initial_call,
                               {mochiweb_acceptor,init,
                                   ['Argument__1','Argument__2',
                                    'Argument__3']}},
                           {pid,<0.349.1>},
                           {registered_name,[]},
                           {error_info,
                               {exit,
                                   {error,accept_failed},
                                   [{mochiweb_acceptor,init,3},
                                    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                           {ancestors,
                               [https,couch_secondary_services,
                                couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                           {messages,[]},
                           {links,[<0.2106.0>,#Port<0.3554>]},
                           {dictionary,[]},
                           {trap_exit,false},
                           {status,running},
                           {heap_size,987},
                           {stack_size,24},
                           {reductions,225918}],
                          []]}}
[Mon, 30 Sep 2013 00:27:57 GMT] [error] [<0.2106.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                         {<0.2106.0>,std_error,
                          {mochiweb_socket_server,310,
                              {acceptor_error,{error,accept_failed}}}}}
```

So please, how to fix this issue?

---

**UPDATE**: It's important to say that **the reason** that mochiweb don't have access to my certificate is that **I ran the couchdb** from `root` user **not from** `couchdb` **user**.

**SO, EVERY TIME KEEP SURE THAT YOU ARE RUNNING YOUR PROGRAMS WITH THE COUCHDB USER**

```
sudo -i -u couchdb couchdb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the updated question. CouchDB was not able to access the certificates. Either because the files are missing, or CouchDB does not have privileges to the files.

Comment: no, I get this error: `curl: option --no-check-certificate: is unknown` the parameter `-k` do that

Comment: Ah, you are right, that was the option for `wget`. Is anything listening on port 6984? You should be able to check that with `netstat -l`

Comment: I think that is normaly, see the answer: `tcp        0      0 *:6984                  *:*                     LISTEN `

Comment: and the answer from wget: 
`--2013-09-29 21:24:58--  https://localhost:6984/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:6984... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.`

Comment: It does look like for whatever reason, couchdb cannot establish an ssl connection. Is there an error log you can look at?

Comment: I add the couch.log at my post.

Comment: It would appear couchdb cannot access the certificates. Does it have read access to them? Does it exist in the lath you set?

Comment: please suggest this on you answer so I make it as a marked answer, because you fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

Also note that there is a problem with certs using sha256 or higher with Erlang prior to version R15B02. Only sha1 or md5 were supported before that release.

[More information is in this discussion thread](https://leap.se/code/issues/883#note-10)